# In MVC, the update action doesn't work and stores the values

Tags: php, sql, model-view-controller

I took over a job from a friend. Now I am working on a MVC, I have made a Form that looks like his:

```
<form method="post" action="QA/public/index.php?controller=QA&action=shabUpdate">
    <table class="clean">
        {data}
        <tr style="display:{display};">
            <td class="label">Specific:</td>
            <td>{remarks}</td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    {back}
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

In my controller I made the following shabUpdateAction:

```
protected function shabUpdateAction()
    {
        $_POST['titel'] = $_POST['titel'];
        /*$_POST['inspectie'] = 'so sorry';
        $_POST['extraDocument'] = 'newIMG';*/

        $this->dbh->setShab($_POST, $_POST['partId']);

        $_SESSION['page'] = './QA/public/index';
        $_SESSION['getIndex'] = '?controller=QA&action=showInspectionDocument&templateId='.$_POST['templateId'];

        header('Location: http://stuffff/something/');
        exit();
    }
```

this is suppose to update my form and when I visit the form page I should be able to see the new information (new changes that was made).
However the update action doesn't work and it doesn't redirect to a correct page.

this is the part from my Model:

```
public function updateSshab($sdr)
    {
        $sql = "UPDATE `qa_template` 
                SET `inspection_requirement` = :requirement
                WHERE `part_id` = :partId AND `title` = :title;";
        $statement = $this->dbh->prepare($sql);
        $statement->bindParam(':requirement', $sdr['defectDescription']);
        $statement->bindParam(':partId', $sdr['partId']);
        $statement->bindValue(':title', 'SDR nummer: SDR' .$sdr['nr']);
        $statement->execute();      
    }
```

and finally my view:

```
public function renderShowInspectionDocument()
    {
        setLastPage();

        $dochtml = '';


        $url = str_replace(end(explode('/', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])), '', $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']);
        //Template
        $template = file_get_contents('templates/inspectionDetails.tpl');

        //shab
        if(isset($this->data['shab']))
        {
            $shab= $this->data['shab']; 

            $dochtml .= '

                <tr>
                    <td class="label">Inspection:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="templateId" value="'.$shab['id'].'" />
                    <div id="testDiv" style="width:420px; font-weight:normal; border-left:1px solid black; border-bottom:1px solid black; padding:5px;"><a href="javascript:changeDiv(\'testDiv\', \'testDiv2\');" title="change" class="edit">'. nl2br($shab['inspection_requirement']) .'</a></div>

                    <div id="testDiv2" style="display=none">
                        <textarea name="inspection" class="width">'. nl2br($shab['inspection_requirement']) .'</textarea>
                    </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="label">Inspection-tools:</td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="hidden" name="templateId" value="'.$shab['id'].'" />
                    <div id="testDiv22" style="width:420px; font-weight:normal; border-left:1px solid black; border-bottom:1px solid black; padding:5px;"><a href="javascript:changeDiv(\'testDiv22\', \'testDiv222\');" title="chang" class="edit">'. nl2br($shab['inspection_resources'])  .'</a></div>
                    <div id="testDiv222" style="display=none">
                        <textarea name="InspectieResources" class="width">'. nl2br($shab['inspection_resources']) .'</textarea>
                    </div>
                    </td>   
                </tr>           
                ';
        }

        $template = str_replace('{data}', $dochtml, $template);
        $template = str_replace('{terug}', backButtonQA(), $template);
        $template = str_replace('{display}', 'none', $template);
        echo $template;
    }
```

my update function doesn't work correctly. I didn't write nu I am working on it and I cant seem to figure out the problem with update Action, is there something I am missing??

Comment: just dont waste time and write your own mvc. there are many for different usecases much better and more performant than you could ever reach as single developer. specially as it looks like you are more or less new. the time you finish your mvc technology has changed. reuse existing composer packages for routing, orm but better use some existing frameworks. laravel, symfony, codeigniter, yii, phalcon, cakephp... all those frameworks are more popular with a big community

Comment: @di3 I do understand your point, but since I tok over this job, I cant for now atleast to write new MVC, maybe in the future, But can u maybe help me with my poblem for now??

Comment: where do you call updateSshab() or shabUpdateAction() how should anyone know what happens in your code. guess you use basice pdo what query is executed or actualy you reach your model? set exception mode log errors whatever your quesion is just mane guessed answers.